# Web development using HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to build a website. I have learned HTML & CSS, have put together few lines of code in my text editor. How do I test this ?

P.S : I have Sublime text 2 installed on my machine. What all things do I need to see how my code works ?

Thanks
Chetan

Comment: Give it an .html extension, open it in your browser of choice.

Comment: This is not a good Stack Overflow question, since it's far too broad. There are many good tutorials for getting started with web design, and also w2schools if you want bad and outdated advice instead. Any worthwhile tutorial will cover this question in much more detail than we can do here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add .html extension to your files which containing html code. And then open it in your browser (for example internet explorer, safari, opera, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You need some way to serve the files (you can open the index.html in the browser, but HTTP calls won't work).

I can think of a simple way involving Python:

1. Go and install [Python 2.7.9](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
2. Open a terminal with Win+r > cmd > Enter
3. Run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`
4. Open `http://127.0.0.1:8000` in your favourite browser
5. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I sublime just go to file>save and save the file as whatever.html on your desktop.

The .html suffix is the important bit.

Then go to your desktop, right click on the file and open with>chrome (or whatever browser you use).

As long as you keep the browser open you can update the code in sublime, save it and refresh the browser to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example in HTML and CSS:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style> 
            h1{color: #cc9900}
            h2{color: #0099cc}
            h3{color: #339900}
            h4{color: #990033}
            h5{color: #cccc00}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>simple HTML & CSS page</h1>
        <h2>simple HTML & CSS page</h2>
        <h3>simple HTML & CSS page</h3>
        <h4>simple HTML & CSS page</h4>
        <h5>simple HTML & CSS page</h5>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now copy the code and open Notepad

1. paste the code in Notepad
2. press `save as` and type the name of your file as you wish (let's have this page name as `sample`, and  since your page is html, add `.html` and finally your file name is `sample.html`)
3. now right click on `sample.html` and choose option `open with` and select the browser you have in your system

Here is [a guide to HTML and CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/).